# SharePoint 2019 Newsfeed Everyone section doesn't work

Tags: my-site, newsfeed, 2019

I have deployed an SP 2019 farm for the first time for development purpose. I have configured User Profile Services and MySite properly. Everything seems work except 2 sections in MySite/NewsFeed.

I am able to see feeds in Following and Mentions sections but there is no feed in Everyone section. It keeps saying:

> We're still collecting the latest news. You may see more if you try again a little later.

Microsoft says below in [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/what-s-deprecated-or-removed-from-sharepoint-server-2019):

> The aggregated newsfeed feature (available at newsfeed.aspx and typically accessed via the Newsfeed tile on the app launcher), will be set to read-only in SharePoint Server 2019.

As my understanding above, Newsfeed works as read only. But in reality it doesn't work that way. When a user -who I follow- posts something in "Site Feed" I can see that in NewsFeed page Following section.

So, my question is:

**Is there any way to make "Everyone section" work in MySite/NewsFeed**